# set react-native-elements checkbox width to screen width

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am using react-native-elements checkbox to display a list of items and a checkbox with them. Problem is that the width of the checkbox control is always equal to the title of the CheckBox itself. How can I make all the checkboxes in the list equal to each other and equal to the screen width?

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide your code?